# Is a ש after a holam always a "shin" and never a "sin"?

Tags: hebrew, prayer-book, aleph-bet-letters, vowels-nekudot

In some siddurim that are printed in certain Hebrew fonts, you will find words such as משה (Moshe) or חשך (darkness) that do not print with two *nekudot*. The most explicit way to point these words would be to have a *holam* over the first consonant and a "shin dot" (what's its real name?) over the shin.

Instead, the siddurim I am referring to only put the *holam* in, not the second dot. In the two examples I give, the ש is indeed supposed to be pronounced as a "shin", but I do not know if this is safe to always assume this.  Are there cases where a ש after a *holam* should actually be pronounced as a "sin"?  How would you recognize those cases, a grammatical rule or just knowing the word?

Comment: עשה שלום במרומיו...

Comment: @DoubleAA Aha, that is a good example and shows how that font handles it and why I didn't recognize it. In that case, the font does print both the *holam* and the "sin dot".  So it seems to drop the second dot for shin, but not for sin.  Thanks.

Comment: I think this is just a modern printing convention. I wouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20568&st=&pgnum=40

Answer (score 1):

See the introduction to the Jerusalem Bible by Koren Publishers.

They go to great lengths to explain how they crafted a font so as to solve the issue you raise: they differentiate between the Cholem and the Shin/Sin dots by height and weight so that you can see both - and not confuse them.

So, as DoubleAA already commented, what you are referring to is simply  a convenience of the [manual] typesetter and then perpetuated by the printers.

Comment: I have also seen variations after a pronounced vav (pronounced vo rather than o)